# ¿Como guardar en un móvil sin tarjeta SD?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código para descargar una música que tengo almacenada en mi servidor el cual funciona perfectamente guardando en un móvil que tiene tarjeta SD en la carpeta "Download", el problema esta en que no se como guardar en la memoria del teléfono, por ejemplo cuando el teléfono no tiene SD, tendría que guardarla en la carpeta "Download" de la memoria del teléfono.

Aclaro que ya use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, se supone que descarga mi archivo, pero no lo veo en la carpeta "Download" de la memoria interna del teléfono.

Espero puedan ayudarme

Dejo mi código actual:

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package com.taber.descarga;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton descargar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        descargar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndescargar);
    }

    public void Descarga(View view) {
        descargar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // execute this when the downloader must be fired
        final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(MainActivity.this);
        downloadTask.execute("aqui va la URL de descarga");
    }


    // usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
    // that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
        public DownloadTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                // this will be useful to display download percentage
                // might be -1: server did not report the length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // Descargar el archivo
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+"nombredelaudio.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) // Sólo si se conoce la longitud total
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // se bloquea la CPU para evitar que la CPU se apague si el usuario
            // presiona el botón de encendido durante la descarga
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    getClass().getName());
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

// si llegamos aquí, se conoce la longitud, ahora se establece indeterminado a falso
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Error en la descarga: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "¡Terminado!, Akmacenado en la carpeta Download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                descargar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.taber.descarga.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Descarga"
            android:text="Descargar"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btndescargando"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btndescargar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_done"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="88dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.taber.descarga">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: A simple vista, no Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); solo traería la dirección en la SD?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que no se, como seria en ese caso para guardar en la memoria interna si el telefono no tiene SD, he probado con esto output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Download/file name.mp3");, pero no se cual seria la ruta si no tiene SD

Answer (score 0):

En realidad estas guardando tu archivo en el almacenamiento externo,

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
input = connection.getInputStream();
output = new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+"nombredelaudio.mp3");
```

Pero si en realidad deseas guardar el archivo en la SDCard, usa `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")`, para obtener el path del SDCard:

```
String path = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
input = connection.getInputStream();
output = new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+"nombredelaudio.mp3");
```